# Usage of "since" vs. "onward"

Tags: prepositions, tense, adverbs, passive-voice, time

> 1. *It has been accepted by Japan since 1950.*
> 2. *It was accepted by Japan 1950 onward.*

It feels like to me that these sentence have the same meaning. I wonder if native speakers of English think so too.

Comment: they are the same! 'since' is used from a particular point of time till now. 'Onward' with specified time also mean the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was accepted by Japan 1950 onward.

is ungrammatical. You must say instead, *accepted by Japan **from** 1950 onward.*

Even with this change the two sentences do not have exactly the same meaning.

When you use the perfect tense, *has been accepted,* you are saying that this information is *relevant to our present circumstance.* Whatever it is that Japan has accepted since 1950, they continue to accept it to this day.

But if you say *was accepted,* you leave open the possibility that Japan has since ceased to accept it. (You'll need to consider the context you're writing in to decide if this could cause confusion.)

We might say, for instance,

> German banks and exchanges used the new Deutsche Mark from 1948 on,

even though they no longer do so (having adopted the Euro in replacement). To say that German banks and exchanges *have used* the DM since 1948 would imply, incorrectly, that they still do so.

Answer (score 0):

- Number 2 should read: "It was accepted by Japan *from* 1950 onward."
- They both mean exactly the same thing.

However, native speakers would almost never choose the sentence construction of #2. #1 would be used approximately 99% of the time in my opinion.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "It was accepted by Japan *from* 1950 onward"?

Comment: @kos: Yes, I agree. I will change my answer. Thanks.